# Filtering a ListFragment from the ActionBar in parent Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-listfragment

I'm hoping you can help me with this.

I have a MainActivity class that holds a ListFragment, and I'm trying to build a search bar into the Action Bar in the MainActivity.

The search bar is there, but I don't know how to filter the list in the ListFragment.

There's a filterList method in the ListFragment that I was going to call from the MainActivity, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Here's what the MainActivity looks like:

```
package dk.mmad.ma1;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private DAO daoAdapter;
private SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

Fragment fragment;

public DAO getDAO() {
    return daoAdapter;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    daoAdapter = new DAO(this);

    getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new BookListFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
    }
}

/**
 * On selecting action bar icons
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        // filter the list
        return true;
    case R.id.add_book:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddBookActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    daoAdapter.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);


 // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));



    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

}
```

And here's the ListFragment:

```
    package dk.mmad.ma1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import db.DAO;
import db.DAO.Books;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class BookListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private DAO daoAdapter;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    long currentId;

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refreshList();
    }

    public void filterList(String query) {
        Cursor cursor = daoAdapter.getBooks(query);
        cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
    }

    private void refreshList() {
        Cursor cursor = daoAdapter.getBooks();
        cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        daoAdapter = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getDAO();
        daoAdapter.open();

        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook1", "author1", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook2", "author3", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook3", "author1", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook4", "author3", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook5", "author1", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook6", "author3", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook7", "author1", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook8", "author3", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook9", "author1", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook10", "author3", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook11", "author1", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook13", "author3", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook14", "author1", 123);
        daoAdapter.saveBook("testbook15", "author3", 123);


        Cursor cursor = daoAdapter.getBooks();
        String[] fromColumns = { "title", "author" };
        int[] toViews = { dk.mmad.ma1.R.id.titleTextView, dk.mmad.ma1.R.id.authorTextView };

        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(((MainActivity)getActivity()),
                dk.mmad.ma1.R.layout.list_item_books, cursor, fromColumns,
                toViews, 0);

        setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        //startManagingCursor(cursor);
    }

/*  @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {        
        Long itemId = getListAdapter().getItemId(position);

        Log.i("Testings", daoAdapter.getBookTitle(itemId));


        //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BookDetailsActivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra("", itemId);
        //startActivity(intent);
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        currentId = id;

        Cursor cursor = cursorAdapter.getCursor();
        String idForIntent = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Books.ID_COL));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
        String author = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("author"));
        String pages = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("page_count"));

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), BookDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("book", new String[] {idForIntent, title, author, pages});
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Can you help me?